# append feature in JLabel like in JTextArea java?

Tags: java, swing, append, jlabel, settext

is there a append feature for JLabel, like in JTextArea?

```
JTextArea Text = new JTextArea("including; "); 
Text.append("button1,");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can do something like this each time you want to add text

```
label.setText(label.getText() + "text u want to append");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a method called `.append(text)`, you can create your own custom Label

```
public class MyLabel extends JLabel {

 public MyLabel(String text) {
    super(text);
 }

 public void append(String appendText) {
   setText(getText() + appendText);
 }
}
```

Than you can create your Label:

```
MyLabel myLabel = new MyLabel("First Text");
myLabel.append("Appended Text");
```